# Split a List in TCL to two equally sized lists

Tags: list, loops, tcl

Is there a better way other than

1. Find the length of the list (`[llength]`)
2. Run a counter to Midway  `[llength]/2`
3. Then Pop out all elements `[lindex $index]` upto `lindex/2`
4. then Do a intersect with the list in step 3 with Original list

It would be really nice if there is a less involved way to pop out one element in list1 and next element in list 2 etc .

Answer (score 3):

```
set len [expr {[llength $src] / 2}]
set left [lrange $src 0 [expr {$len - 1}]]
set right [lrange $src $len end]
```

You might also first check that the full length is an even number greater or equal than two.

Comment: The answer will still be “correct” if the length is odd, but the lengths won't be the same. Similarly, a very short input list will result in one (or both!) of the output lists being empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a foreach loop.

```
set pairedlist [list "FirstName" "Tony" "LastName" "Bennett"]

set keys [list]
set values [list]

foreach {key value} $pairedlist {
  puts "$key: $value"
  lappend keys $key
  lappend values $value
}

puts $keys
puts $values
```